# zsh: create named file in place of argument?

Tags: zsh

`realpath <<<'foo'` fails "realpath: missing operand". I don't know what that means.

`realpath <(<<<'foo')` returns `/proc/3443695/fd/pipe:[26244650]` which I guess means it's creating a temporary pipe which will contain the string "foo".

Or maybe `printf` is more clear:

```sh
❯ printf "%q" <<<'foo'  # no output
❯ printf "%q" <(<<<'foo')
/proc/self/fd/11%
```

The actual program I'm trying to call doesn't like either of those. I think I need an actual file.

I can do that in multiple commands by creating a file with `mktemp` and then writing to it, and then sending that off as the arg, but does zsh have any convenient syntax for doing this in-place? A 1-liner?

Comment: `realpath` does not read stdin. Therefore `realpath <<<foo` does not make sense.

Comment: @user1934428 Right. I wasn't quite sure what `<<<` did exactly. I guess it sends the string on the right to `stdin`? `<<` starts a heredoc, and `<` sends the *file* on the right to stdin?

Comment: Still confused about `<(<<<'foo')` syntax then. If "foo" is going to stdin in a subshell, and `<` is expecting a filename, how do get "/proc/self/fd/11" as an argument out of that?

Comment: I have never seen a `<(<<<something)`. IMO, it would create a subshell in which nothing happens except input redirection, and which therefore would also not produce any output. My feeling is that if such a construct is legal, it would be equivalent to `</dev/null`.  The FD 11 is likely the file descriptor which was created for your process substitution. You would get the same effect with the simpler command `printf %q <(:)`.

Comment: Note also that `printf` does not read stdin, so a `printf <something` does not make much sense anyway. See _man printf_.

Comment: @mpen: Note that `<...` (redirection) is not the same as `<(...)` (process
substitution).  Angle brackets are used for many different things in shell syntax; confusion is very normal :).

Comment: @user1934428: `<(<<<something)` does produce output - try `cat <(<<<something)`. It can be used to send text via a here-string (`<<<`) to a program that only accepts input files and doesn't understand stdin. `<(print something)` would achieve the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `=(list)` process substitution should do what you want.

From the `zshexpn` man page:

> If =(...) is used instead of <(...), then the file passed as  an
> argument  will be the name of a temporary file containing the output
> of the list process.  This may be used instead of the <  form  for  a
> program that expects to lseek on the input file.
> ...
> The temporary file created by the process substitution will be deleted when the function exits.

On my system, `realpath =(<<<'foo')` returns something like `/private/tmp/zsh3YAdDx`, i.e. the name of a temporary file that does indeed appear to be deleted after executing the  command.

As a bonus, the documentation notes that in some cases the `=(<<<...)` form is optimized to execute completely in the current shell.

Comment: Very cool! Zsh has an operator for everything 